# Stop C# Uri constructor from encoding the url (vertical bar)

Tags: c#, .net, url, get, uri

I need to send a GET request to an address that contains unescaped '|' (the vertical bar). The server (not mine) won't take in the queries with escaped | (i.e %7C)

However, whenever I construct a new Uri from the address, I can see `absoluteUri` contains an escaped version of my address (%7C).

Is there a way to just send a GET request with unescaped |in C#?

(Using .NET 4.5)

Any help would be appreciated! thanks.

EDIT:

```
    string formUrl = "http://example.com/|12|"; //just an example  
Uri temp = new Uri(formUrl);  
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(temp);
                req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                req.CookieContainer = cookies;
                req.Method = "GET";
                req.KeepAlive = true;
                req.KeepAlive = true;
                HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
                List<string> gethtml = new List<string>();
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                        gethtml.Add(sr.ReadLine());
                }
                resp.Dispose();
```

The vertical bar/pipe character is encoded into %7C if I look at temp.AbsoluteUri.

Thanks!

Comment: is it impacting the functionality, because I don't think it should..

Comment: also, the character is called pipe, i think

Comment: "However, whenever I construct a new Uri from the address".. can you qualify this statement?.. are you referring to using the `Uri` .Net type here?  can you provide a code snippet of your attempt to send the request with a GET method?

Comment: I edited the post thanks for the help!

Comment: ive seen a lot of names for the character pipe vbar  haha

Answer (score 0):

The `WebRequest.Create` method has an overload that takes a string. So you could just do:

```
var req = WebRequest.Create(temp.AbsoluteUrl.Replace("%7C", "|");
```

This does however have a potential problem: if for some reason your url can legitimally contain `%7C` already, it will also be replaced. If that's a problem, the following approach is clumsier but works (replace `--PIPE--` for anything else if required):

```
var tempFormUrl = formUrl.Replace("|","--PIPE--");
var temp = new Uri(tempFormUrl);
var req = WebRequest.Create(temp.AbsoluteUrl.Replace("--PIPE--", "|");
```

Comment: this was like my original approach. but string passed to WebRequest.Create actually is constructed into Uri class anyways so the problem still persists :/ thanks for the help anyways:)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find a way to circumvent the annoying Uri parsing away my pipe character.
So the method i used is to use `Socket` to send a GET request as this process won't involve any `Uri` :0)

At least now the server is recognizing my requests and giving the information I want.